# Receiving an R-based error message in Azure ML but not in R itself

Tags: r, azure

This is my first time posting so I apologize if I don't have all my crap together.

I am fairly new to Azure ML and R, but I am trying to implement a Logit model through R in Azure since it doesn't seem to be one of the Microsoft-provided models in Azure ML.

When I run my model and other code in RStudio, I don't get any errors, but when I try to implement it through a "Create R Module" in Azure, I get an error message saying:

"Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:
---------- Start of error message from R ----------
cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame
----------- End of error message from R -----------"

There seems to be very little Azure ML documentation that covers R model creation out there, so I thought I would turn here for some potential answers. It is likely that I am just missing something.

Here is the code I have been running:

> Blockquote Trainer Script
>
> model<-glm(Mat_Bin~Mat.Mkt.Pen+debt+Urban.Vmi+GDP.Per.Capita+Avg.Low+MSAcrash, data=data, family=binomial)
>
> Scorer R Script
>
> scores<-as.data.frame(predict(model, subset(data, select=c(predict.MatModel3.))))
>
> names(scores)<-c("Predicted Values")

I tried to upload pictures of everything, but apparently I need higher reputation to do so. But my experiment is super simple. Just some simple column manipulation and then the training and scoring of my model.

Any ideas on why I am getting that error message?

Comment: Could you post the data? Best would be a small subset of the data that produces the same error so we can try it out.

Comment: I think we'll better be able to help you if you could provide a [minimum reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In particular, we would need a sample dataset `data` and code that can be applied to `data` that causes the error.

Comment: In R the token `data` is a function. People are generally advised not to name their data-objects "data" because the error messages get rather confusing. R is suppose to keep a wall between function names and other object names but you may have stumbled across an infelicity of AzureML if in fac there is a "data"-data-object and the evaluation has gone off-road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a simple naming error on your part, you could try:

```
model <- glm(Mat_Bin ~ Mat.Mkt.Pen + debt + Urban.Vmi+ GDP.Per.Capita + Avg.Low+MSAcrash, 
             data=scores, family=binomial)
```